# Incrementing menu levels

Tags: php, html

I'm trying create a page that displays a multi level menu.

For example my menu looks like this

```
Home
About
Product
    - Watches
        - Rolex
        - Some other watch
    - Tops
    - Pants
Contact
```

As you can see it has more then 2 levels. What I'm trying to do is find out what level I'm on so that I can
style it accordingly.

So for example `Home, About, Product, Contact` would be level 1, `Watches, Tops, Pants` would be level 2
and `Rolex, Some other watch` would be level 3.

I would like to do this dynamically so that if I ended up having even more levels I can then style as needed.
At the moment my code isn't incrementing how I would like it

This is my code

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" width="90%">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php
            echo admin_menus();
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>


function admin_menus($parent_id = 0, $level = 1)
{
    global $conn;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM menus WHERE parent_id = ".$parent_id;
    $menus = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    confirmQuery($menus);

    // Checks to see if there is any rows in the table
    if(mysqli_num_rows($menus) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($menus))
        {
            $menu_id = $row['id'];
            $menu_title = $row['title'];
            $menu_position = $row['position'];

            if($parent_id > 0)
            {
                $sub_menu = "sub-menu";
                $sub_icon = "<i class='fa fa-angle-right pr-10'></i>";
            }else{
                $sub_menu = "";
                $sub_icon = "";
            }

            echo "<tr class='$level' data-index='$menu_id' data-position='$menu_position'>";
            echo    "<td>";
            echo        "<div class='$sub_menu'>";
            echo            $sub_icon;
            echo            "<a href='menus.php?source=edit_menu&m_id=$menu_id'>";
            echo                $menu_title;
            echo            "</a>";
            echo        "</div>";
            echo    "</td>";

            echo    "<td>";
            echo        "<div class='dropdown text-center'>";
            echo            "<button class='btn btn-sm btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' id='dropdownActionButton' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspop='true' aria-expanded='false'>";
            echo                "<i class='fa fa-cogs'></i>";
            echo            "</button>";

            echo            "<div class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right' aria-labelledby='dropdownActionButton'>";
            echo                "<a href='menus.php?source=edit_menu&m_id=$menu_id' class='dropdown-item'>";
            echo                    "Edit";
            echo                "</a>";

            echo                "<a href='menus.php?delete=$menu_id' class='dropdown-item'>";
            echo                    "Delete";
            echo                "</a>";
            echo            "</div>";
            echo        "</div>";
            echo    "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            // Increments the level
            $multi_level = $level++;

            admin_menus($menu_id, $level);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't it easier to just style on `.child()`?

Comment: I would still need to know what level I'm at wouldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this type of feature in the past. So I'm sharing my **PHP + MySQL** code with you. I wanna tell you that I am not sharing code with **CSS**.

[image: My Database Table which I have used for the menu.]

**Now I am creating DB connection.**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","sql_testing");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

**Now I am creating a function which helps me to create a menu.**

```
function creatMenu($parentId,$con) 
{
    $html = "";
    $SQL = " SELECT * FROM menu_trees where parent_id='" .$parentId . "' ";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$SQL);
    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
           $html .="<li><a href='#'>".$result['name']."</a>";          
           $html .= "<ul>".creatMenu($result['id'])."</ul>";           
           $html .= "</li>"; 
    }    
    return $html;
}
```

**Now my HTML code starts:**

```
<ul>
    <!-- I am calling a function for create menu-->
    <?=creatMenu(0,$con);?>
</ul>
```

**Now I am closing the MySQL connection.**

Note:- Maybe My description is not appropriate but I'm trying to improve. If you have any queries, please let me.
Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this similar to what I have already? My `admin_menus()` function

Comment: Yes, I have tried your code for the menu tree and by using this, I achieve more nested levels. That's why I posted here.

Comment: Problem is I would like to keep my table and from what I can see your code only works if it's a list.

Comment: So I've added the rest of my table to my question. So what happens is that on my index.php page I will have the `<table>` section and then when you get to the `<tbody>` you then go to the  `admin_menus()` function.